# MySQL timestamp to Java date conversion

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

How can I convert time in unix timestamp to normal time?

Comment: Your question is vague and ambiguous. Don't you just mean "How to convert a timestamp in (milli)seconds to a human readable time format of HH:mm:ss"? [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) is namely a timezone, as is [GMT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time).

Comment: @BalusC that is incorrect GMT is GMT all the time, the British daylight savings time is BST which is GMT+1, GMT doesn't vary from UTC by anything more than negligible fractions of a second which aren't relevant in day to day use.

Comment: @MrXexxed: I edited the DST part away for the sake that.

Comment: @BalusC thanks, looks better now! But your point is valid, the questions title *is* misleading as for the purposes of this UTC and GMT are the same thing.

Comment: Title says mysql timestamp, question asks unix timestamp.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your question is vague and ambiguous. I'll leave the timezone ambiguity away.

> *How can I convert time in unix timestamp to normal time?*

I suspect that you're somehow obtaining a `long` or maybe a `String` value from the DB instead of a `Date`. In JDBC, you would normally like to use the appropriate methods to obtain the DB-specific datatypes. The MySQL `TIMESTAMP` datatype can be obtained by [`ResultSet#getTimestamp()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28java.lang.String%29) which gives you a [`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) which in turn is a subclass of [`java.util.Date`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

In a nut, the following should do:

```
Date date = resultSet.getTimestamp("columnname");
```

To format it further in a human readable format whenever you're going to present it to the enduser, use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Click the link, it contains an overview of all patterns. Here's an example:

```
String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date);
```

To do all the other way round, use respectively [`SimpleDateFormat#parse()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) and [`PreparedStatement#setTimestamp()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp%28int,%20java.sql.Timestamp%29).

Answer (score 3):

Unix timestamp is seconds since "epoch". Java's currentTimeMillis are milliseconds since "epoch". You can get a Java Date object with a simple multiplication like this:

```
 Date dateFromUnixTime = new Date( 1000l * unixTime) ;
```

From there, you can format it using the normal date formatting tools in Java.