# Problem with Date Format in Java

Tags: java

I have a problem with this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException { 
    String strDate = "2011-01-12 07:50:00";
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd H:M:S");
    Date date = formatter.parse(strDate);
    System.out.println("Date="+date);
}
```

The output is:
Date=Thu Feb 12 07:**01**:00 EET **2015**
What am i doing wrong??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Upper case M is the day of the month designator.  Lower case m is the minute in the hour.  Also, you want lower case s, as upper case S is milliseconds.

That said, what you need may be closer to this

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

Answer (score 3):

Your format is wrong, see [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

You want this instead,

```
String strDate = "2011-01-12 07:50:00";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

This might have some use hopefully: [Extract time from date String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504986/java-date-time-format)

Modify the 'H:mm' to whatever you want the format to be.

Answer (score 0):

as your question you check 
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd H:M:S"); in this statement 
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" is  the SimpleDateFormate.