# Time Conversion from 12-hour to 24-hour clock in Java

Tags: java, datetime, syntax, datetime-conversion

I have a time in a string in the following format.

```
"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM"
```

I need to get the time in `24:00` hours format

ex:

```
String str = "04/30/2013 10:20PM"
```

I need to get the time as `22:20`

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use SimpleDateFormat to any kind of date-time conversion.
You can try this:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DateConversion {
   public void convertDate() {
      try{
       SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
       SimpleDateFormat pf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a");
       Date date = pf.parse("10:20PM");
       System.out.println(pf.format(date) + " = " + df.format(date));
        }catch(Exception e){
        // Do your exception handling over here.
        }
   }
}
```

This will solve your problem I guess.
This will give an output : `22:20`

Please let me know in case of any issue.

Comment: Make `pf` "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a" to match the full string.

Comment: Date date = pf.parse(dateStr);
Time time = new Time(date.getTime()); This will give time in sql time format.

Answer (score 3):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert a string to a Date object and then format it.

```
String str = "04/30/2013 10:20PM";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma").parse(str);
String result = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(date);
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504986/java-date-time-format) for a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

Use "HH" instead of "hh" For example:

```
Date dNow = new Date( );
SimpleDateFormat ft =   new SimpleDateFormat ("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm ");
System.out.println("Current Date: " + ft.format(dNow));
```

[in this link, specially in "Simple DateFormat format codes:"](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm)  you can find that :

```
Character   Description               Example

h           Hour in A.M./P.M. (1~12)    12
H           Hour in day (0~23)          22
```