# convert a date object to Oracle timestamp type string

Tags: java, oracle

I want to convert a date object, `ex: new Date()`, to a string which has a format like Oracle's time stamp type, `ex: 21-OCT-13 11.08.13.858000000 AM`. I know I could just get each piece of information in the date object like `day, month, year, hour, minute, ...` to form the Oracle format string but I really want to know is there a utility to do that instead?

Comment: Oracle's date/timestamp doesn't have a format. Do you mean that you want it to be as the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` ? or do you just need something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504986/java-date-time-format/3505033#3505033) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try taking a look at [SimpleDateFormats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) - That would be your best bet and easiest way of doing it.

Eg:

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss"); //Hours:Minutes:Seconds
String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: Thx a lot for your quick, exact answer :D

Answer (score 7):

Using `SimpleDateFormat#format()` you would print a `Date` as

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSSSSS a");
System.out.println(sdf.format(new Date()).toUpperCase());
```

*Output :*

```
21-OCT-13 10.01.38.000000614 AM
```

See [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for Date and Time patterns.

Answer (score 1):

Use **SimpleDateFormat**.

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("your_format_here"); // dd/MM/yy h:mm:ss a
String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```