# Trouble parsing Java Date Object?

Tags: java, date

I am receiving a Java Date formatted like so: `"Sun Sep 14 02:00:00 PDT 2014"` into a `yyyy-MM-dd` format but I can't seem to parse it. What I tried is the following:

```
String time = "Sun Sep 14 02:00:00 PDT 2014";
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date contractEffectiveDateFormat = f.parse(time);
System.out.println("Date: " + contractEffectiveDateFormat);
```

However, I get an error saying that this date is unparsable.  I'm not sure how to go about parsing this date because if I try to parse the date using the following:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

which is how to actually parse the date correctly into a Date object,
the string would turn into a Date object, but I can't seem to do anything with it from there. I want to turn it in so that it looks like `2014-09-14`. Any ideas on how to do so? Thanks!

Comment: `Sun Sep 14 02:00:00 PDT 2014` does not match the pattern `yyyy-MM-dd` you need to find a pattern that does

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java date/time format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504986/java-date-time-format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two `DateFormat`(s) one for input and for output,

```
String time = "Sun Sep 14 02:00:00 PDT 2014";
DateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateFormat in = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy");
try {
    Date effectiveDate = in.parse(time);
    System.out.println("Date: " + out.format(effectiveDate));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output is the requested

```
Date: 2014-09-14
```

Answer (score 3):

Your incoming string is this `String time = "Sun Sep 14 02:00:00 PDT 2014";`
which means the SimpleDateFormat pattern should match the incoming String pattern so you need to use SimpleDateFormat like this

```
DateFormat inFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Then when you called parse() on inFormat it will give you Date Object which doesnot have particular format associated with it. So in order to format the Date again you need to create SimpleDateFormat object specifying the format you want which is this

```
DateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Ultimately bind all together

*One more thing always specify the* **Locale**

```
String time = "Sun Sep 14 02:00:00 PDT 2014";
DateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
// good practice to specify the locale
DateFormat inFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);
try {
    Date parsedDate = inFormat.parse(time);
    System.out.println("Required Formatted Date: " + outFormat.format(effectiveDate));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add another `SimpleDateFormat` that'll allow you to present the `Date` object the way you want:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    String time = "Sun Sep 14 02:00:00 PDT 2014";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy");
    Date contractEffectiveDateFormat = df.parse(time);
    System.out.println("Date: " + contractEffectiveDateFormat);

    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    System.out.println(f.format(contractEffectiveDateFormat)); // prints 2014-09-14
}
```