# Making a time object from int values

Tags: java, android

I have two int variables containing

```
Int hour=13,minute=8;
```

I want to convert them into a time object in format like `13:08:00.0000000`

What's the `standard` way of doing it and of making time object out of this string?

Eventually I will convert back that time object into string for use but I want to standardize the string.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Java's **Calendar** or **Date** object. I suggest using [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), very powerful and easy to use.

With JodaTime

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime().withHourOfDay(hour).withMinuteOfHour(minute);
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String dateString = fmt.print(dt);
```

Comment: In fact, if you can, use threetenbp instead of Joda Time; same author(s), with the advantage that it "prepares" you for using Java 8's date/time API (which is JSR 310; threetenbp is "310 BackPort")

Answer (score 0):

May not be the most smart way, but it should work. You can change your hour and minute to String, then use SimpleDateFormat to format it:

```
String originalString = new Integer(hour).toString()+":"+new Integer(minute).toString()+":00.000000";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").parse(originalString);
String newString = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(date);
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3504986/java-date-time-format)

Answer (score 0):

"standard" is a very abstract concept, specially in computing, and even more with Date time, and I've seen people doing all type of crazy things, I'll answer what I believe is the best way of dealing with it.

**manipulation:**

For general manipulation during Runtime handling of time you should use a [`Calendar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) object, either using the static `Calender.getInstance()` or directly instantiating a `GregorianCalendar` with **`new`**. There're several other classes that deal with the same problem like `Time` or `Date` but all of them are either limited or not recommended anymore.
With this class you can use to compare, transform, set values, etc.

**on screen representation/format:**

To format a representation of the `Calendar` on screen (a String) you can use either a [`DateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) or a [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). They will make the human readable value you need to show on screen, by calling `DateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());`

**save/restore:**

Last but not least, if you want to save this value (in a SharedPreferences, SQL database, or anywhere) you should use a `long` as UNIX EPOCH. Number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970. To get the current value on Runtime you can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` or to set/extract from a `Calendar` is as simple as `Calendar.getTimeInMillis()` `Calendar.setTimeInMillis(long milliseconds)`