# How to convert a string into DateTime or TimeStamp of MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

```
m dd yyyy hh:mm:ss
5 12 2015 17:40:53
```

This needs to be stored in a column of a MySQL Table, whose data type is TimeStamp

Comment: `select str_to_date('5 12 2015 17:40:53','%m %d %Y %H:%i:%s') as date ;`

Comment: post what you have tried.

Comment: It's already there - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3473459/2445298

Comment: Already tried select str_to_date('5 12 2015 17:40:53','%m %d %Y %H:%i:%s')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
String yourString = "5 12 2015 17:40:53";
Timestamp timestamp = null;

try{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    Date parsedDate = sdf.parse(yourString);
    timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
}catch(Exception e){
 //this generic but you can control the type of exception
}
```

Comment: Worked, but was trying this with database queries and not by java.